# Script editor creating a folder and naming it

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

So I've been trying to write an AppleScript script that would create a folder with an input of user, but unfortunately I can't get it working. Any help is appreciated.

```
set theResponse to display dialog "Enter the name of folder" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
display dialog "Name of the folder:  " & (text returned of theResponse) & "."
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"theResponse"}
end tell
```

Comment: What are you using to write your script? bash, node.js...?

Comment: @stealththeninja: That looks like AppleScript to me (the default language of Script Editor).

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question, select the code and click the code formatting icon `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified version of your code that will work:

```
set theResponse to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the name of folder" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
display dialog "Name of the folder:  " & theResponse & "."
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:theResponse}
end tell
```

In your original *code*, `{name:"theResponse"}`, with `"theResponse"` in quotes, it's literally `theResponse` not `the text returned`.

So, In the first line of *code*, I started off with setting the `theResponse` *variable* to `the text returned`, so it need not be referenced as such later in the script.

Thus `(text returned of theResponse)` in the second line of *code* is now set to just `theResponse`, which contains the *value* of that *variable*.

Now when it comes time to `make new folder` the `name` *property* is the *value* of `theResponse`, without quotes, and it already contains `the text returned` from the first line of *code*.